# how to write RESTful API specification for angular 2 app?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular area. I have created self service kiosk using angular 2 and now i want to write RESTful API to communicate with asp.net app. How can i write RESTful API Specification?

Comment: ...by working out what the requirements and constraints are for your application and documenting them?

Comment: You need a MCVE. Please include the code you have tried and what you think is going wrong.

Comment: hi Obsidian Age.

Comment: This is too broad. One thing to think about is that the "asp.net app" you mention can easily expose a RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

First Create MVC Web API projects using ASP.NET. Methods are in the controller work as REST API. BUT you have to return JSON results for your angular app.

You can test your API by using POSTMan before bind to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 ->  First step is that we need to configure HttpModule in imports metadata of @NgModule decorator in our application module.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
---------
  imports: [     
        BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ]
---------
})
```

Step-2 ->  We should perform server communication in a service class and not in component. This approach is preferable by design. In a service class we will use dependency injection to get the instance of angular Http as given below.

```
constructor(private http:Http) { }
```

Step-3 -> Now we are ready post

`Observable<Response> ob = this.http.post(this.url, book, options);`

Example ->

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Book } from './book';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
    url = "api/books";
    constructor(private http:Http) { }
    getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now we can use HttpClientModule (introduced from angular version 4.3.0.)instead of HttpModule. One of the most notable changes is that now the response object is a JSON by default, so there's no need to parse it with map method.we can import from  @angular/common/http. import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: but the question was asked angular 2

Answer (score 0):

1.First Create Asp .net MVC Web API Project (EventController create)

2.Craete Angular Application

3.Create Service file Using Angular CLI (ng g s event)

4.Add HttpModule,JsonpModule imports application module and add provider to EventService.

```
import { EventService } from './events/event.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({

  imports: [     
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    EventServise,
  ],

})
```

5.Edit event.service.ts file (Asp.net Project Without Cross Origin Add )

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  setMethod(event:any){
    console.log(event);

    return this.http.post('/events', event).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
  getAllEventData(){

    return this.http.get('/events').map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }


}
```

6. create a new file called proxy.conf.json in the root of the project and inside of that define your proxies like below

   ```
      {
     "/": {
       "target": "http://localhost:8090/api",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
   ```

if we add Cross origin for asp .net web api.we can use without proxy.conf.json so we can edit step 5

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


    @Injectable()
    export class EventService {

      constructor(private http: Http) { }

      setMethod(event:any){
        console.log(event);

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/api/events', event).map((response: Response) => response.json());
      }
      getAllEventData(){

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/api/events').map((response: Response) => response.json());
      }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one its free:
A CRUD API for many MySQL Systems, and others in the future

Single file PHP 5.6 script that adds a REST API to a MySQL 5.6 InnoDB, MariaDB databases.

[Transaction_CRUD_API](https://github.com/shangab/transaction_crud_api)